# Create custom clipboardData property for ClipboardEvent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, karma-jasmine

In my Karma-Jasmine tests I have to test my `onPaste` method.

`onPaste` method:

```
onPaste(event: any): void {
  const pastedText = event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  // some stuff
}
```

My unit test:

```
it('should do something', () => {
  const queryField = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type="search"]')).nativeElement;
  queryField.dispatchEvent(new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
    dataType: 'text/plain',
    data: '325435956\r325435956',
  }));
  // some stuff
})
```

And I use Chrome to run the tests but `new ClipboardEvent()` in Chrome creates `ClipboardEvent` object where `clipboardData` is `null` and `event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain')` throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of null
```

It doesn't happen in Firefox, so if I use `karma-firefox-launcher` it works fine, but I have to use Chrome. So, I had some ideas how to solve it.

The first idea was to create `ClipboardEvent` object and override clipboardData property:

```
const pasteEvent = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {
  dataType: 'text/plain',
  data: '325435956\r325435956',
});

pasteEvent.clipboardData = {
  getData() {
    return this.data;
  }
};
```

But I can't do it because `clipboardData` is a read-only property.

The second idea was to create fake `ClipboardEvent` object:

```
function FakePasteEvent(options) {
  this.clipboardData = {
    dataType: options.dataType,
    data: options.data,
    getData() {
      return this.data;
    }
  };
}
const pasteEvent = new FakePasteEvent({
  dataType: 'text/plain',
  data: '325435956\r325435956',
});

console.log(pasteEvent.clipboardData.getData()) // returns what I need
```

But I can't pass it to `dispatchEvent` because the type of `pasteEvent` is not Event. Then I thought I can specify prototype object for my `FakePasteEvent`:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(pasteEvent, ClipboardEvent);
```

But anyway I've got an error:

`TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'`

Can you help me to solve this problem? ;)

Code example here http://jsbin.com/puqilivalo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quite interestingly, I am currently struggling on who is right between chrome and Firefox on this, I still can't figure out what [the specs](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#clipboard-event-interfaces) tell when they say

> ```
> dictionary ClipboardEventInit : EventInit {
>  DataTransfer? clipboardData = null;
> };
> ```

and

> ```
> [Constructor (DOMString type, optional ClipboardEventInit eventInitDict), Exposed=Window]
>  interface ClipboardEvent : Event {
>  readonly attribute DataTransfer? clipboardData;
> };
> ```

I would tend to say that Chrome is right when it returns null for the `clipboardData` property, but then the very next example makes FF behavior correct:

> Example 3
>   var pasteEvent = new ClipboardEvent('paste');
>   pasteEvent.clipboardData.items.add('My string', 'text/plain');
>   document.dispatchEvent(pasteEvent);

---

---

But anyway, Chrome does support (partially) the [DataTransfer](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#datatransfer) contructor, whereas FF still doesn't. And you can then construct your event with this DataTransfer object in chrome too:

```js
var dT = null;
try{ dT = new DataTransfer();} catch(e){}
var evt = new ClipboardEvent('paste', {clipboardData: dT});
console.log('clipboardData available: ', !!evt.clipboardData);
evt.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'Hello world');

document.onpaste = function(e){
  console.log('onpaste: ', e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
};
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: @artiek I edited with full procedure and here is an update to your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xahaquxodo/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Firefox started supporting the `DataTransfer` constructor after this answer was written, so it can now work without the try/catch and be simplified to just `new ClipboardEvent('paste', {clipboardData: new DataTransfer()});`